# PhpMyAdmin error executing the previous query when trying to browse a table

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I tried to update a certain field on my database and it success
then after a while, I try to browse the table but unfortunately when I try to browse the table

It executes a query

[image: here is the error when i try to click the tbl_assets table]

Comment: Did you connect the words 'update' and 'tbl_assets'?

Comment: actually that was my previous query but that query is correctly written and it was executed well then after a while when i click the tbl_assets to browse it, it return that query.

Answer (score 0):

`phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs` may contain bogus `prefs` value, in a *tbl_assets* table row